# On AVR-GCC, how can I find out what statically initialized variable is using up my RAM?

Tags: avr, flash, ram

The variable does not show up on the MAP file so it is hard to track it down. I'd rather not have to manually search though all the source code looking for static initializers.

Comment: Could you temporarily `#define static extern` to get everything into the map file?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Great point. Title updated to reflect `avr-gcc`. Thanks!

Comment: @RussellBorogove I think you not have a static initializer on an `extern` so this would fail syntactically?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a statically initialized variable like...

`const int numbers[] = { 12 , 13 , 4 , 17 , 12 , 9 };`

...then it will not only use up flash, but also RAM even though it is `const`. To keep it from using up RAM, you must make it `PROGMEM` - but first you have to find which variable is using up the RAM which can be very hard if it is declared with `static` scope like this...

`static const int numbers[] = { 12 , 13 , 4 , 17 , 12 , 9 };`

...since then it will not show up individually in the MAP file.

To track these down, you use use the debug info in the ELF file. Here is a Linux command line that will use the BINUTILS to list all of the variables in a file including the statically scoped ones...

```
avr-readelf -a example.elf | sort -k 2
```

The stuff between the `__data_start` and `__data_end` are the variables that will be copied from flash into RAM...

```
99: 00800100     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __data_start
 1: 00800100     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
38: 00800100    12 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _ZL7numbers
77: 0080010c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __data_end
91: 0080010c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _edata
```

You can ignore the 1st number. The 2nd number is the address in the FLASH that the static data landed at, and the 3rd number is the number of bytes used (in this case 12 bytes). Now you can track those down and make them into `PROGMEM` and save some RAM.

Comment: You should be able to see the utilization of RAM variables as well if you sort the symbols from the objdump output.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is there a reason why const values are copied to RAM? Something about the AVR architecture or memory access time?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson reading directly from progmem needs different instructions and because no-one seems to be able to handle progmem pointers consistently the compiler pulls in the const globals into RAM

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Adding to @rachratchet_freak's point, this is just a limitation of the AVR-GCC compiler. It would certainly be *possible* to keep `const`s in flash and then emit different instructions (i.e. `LPM` rather than `LDS`) and patterns when these variables are accessed, but it is more work for the compiler writer. Easier to move them to RAM and then always emit the same code for any variable read.

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you give an example of an `obj-dump` command line and output that shows statically scoped variable names? I could not figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: The -t flag should do it, if you run on an unstripped elf for example

Comment: @ChrisStratton Confirmed: the `-t` on `obj-dump` on an ELF also works great! Thanks!